# problema consulta mysqli (consultar y agrupar a la vez)

Tags: mysql

Buenas pues mi duda es tengo una tabla prestamo con los campos
id_pres, id_grupo_prestamo, fecha_prestamo,fecha_entrega, id_bien, entregado

donde el id grupo prestamo busca es agrupar cuando 2 o mas bienes del mismo tipo son prestados a la vez (siendo este nulo si se presta 1 solo bien) mi duda es, al momento de una consulta general como podria mostrar todos los registros agrupando los que tengan el mismo id_grupo_prestamo pero mostrand separados los que tengan ese valor nulo

Ejemplo:

base de datos:

```
id   grupo_prestamo   fecha_prestamo   Fecha de entrega   Entregado   id_bie 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    null             4/7/2022         5/7/2022           si          1 
2    1                5/7/2022         7/7/2022           no          2 
3    1                5/7/2022         7/7/2022           no          2 
4    null             5/7/2022         7/7/2022           no          1 
5    null             6/7/2022         7/7/2022           no          2
```

salida de la consulta:(supongamos que el bien con id 1 son mesas y el 2 sillas)

```
bien    cantidad    prestamo    entrega 
-----------------------------------------
Mesas   1           4/7/2022    5/7/2022 
Sillas  2           5/7/2022    7/7/2022 
Mesas   1           5/7/2022    7/7/2022 
Sillas  1           6/7/2022    7/7/2022
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias mostrar un ejemplo de tu salida, y tus datos de entrada? me parece que lo que queres no se puede.. pero por si acaso, pone un ejemplo...

Comment: un ejemplo bueno digamos que tengo 5 mesas prestadas hoy y 1 mesa prestada ayer y 1 computadora prestada hoy quisiera que al momento de hacer la consulta solo me muestre la fecha de ayer con la mesa prestada, la fecha de hoy con las 5 mesas prestadas y la fecha de hoy con la computadora prestada, no se si me explico tratare de editar la pregunta para hacerlo un poco mas grafico

Comment: Eso no es un ejemplo.. un ejemplo es en la pregunta, usas el boton [edit] y agregas algo con lo que quien te quiere contestar puede trabajar... si queres ayuda, tenes que ayudarnos a ayudarte ;)

Comment: coloque dos imagenes espero que con eso quede claro

Comment: no estas agrupando por las dos fechas y el bien?

Comment: Si pones los ejemplos de datos como texto bien indentandos es mucho mejor para analizar o reproducir el problema (me he permitido recuperar el texto e indentarlo), aunque para bases de datos lo mejor de lo mejor sería que nos mostraras un fiddle. Dicho eso, tienes un gravísimo problema de diseño y eso dificulta cualquier operación sencilla. Para empezar, tus fechas de préstamo y entrega redundan en ambas tablas. ¿Por qué? Debes considerar seriamente evitar esa redundancia. Deberías tener una tabla sólo con los bienes y la cantidad podría ir en la primera tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser creando una consulta que sea la unión de dos consultas: una para los préstamos individuales y otra para los agrupados:

```
SELECT 
  /* Aquí simulo la unión (join) con la tabla de bienes */
  CASE 
    WHEN x.id_bien = 1 THEN 'Mesas'
    ELSE 'Sillas'
  END AS bien,
  /* ------------------------------------------- */
  x.cantidad,
  x.prestamo,
  x.entrega
FROM (
  -- Agrupados
  SELECT 
    MIN(id) as id,  -- Usar min para ordenar por orden de registro en tabla
    MAX(id_bien) as id_bien,
    SUM(1) AS cantidad,
    -- En teoría debería ser la misma fecha para cualquiera del grupo
    MAX(fecha_prestamo) AS prestamo,  
    MAX(fecha_entrega) AS entrega     
    -- ********************************
  FROM prestamos
  WHERE grupo_prestamo IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY grupo_prestamo
 
  UNION 

  -- No agrupados
  SELECT 
    id,
    id_bien,
    1 as cantidad,
    fecha_prestamo AS prestamo,
    fecha_entrega AS entrega     
  FROM prestamos
  WHERE grupo_prestamo IS NULL) as x
ORDER BY x.id;  -- Ordenar por orden de registro en table
```